# Run a script every time a shell is spawned

Tags: bash

I need a way to make a script run at all times under all users and to automatically start if any new shell is spawned. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you understand the implications of this. Shells are spawned for a large number of things, and not just for user interactions.

Comment: And this is something that must be run every time.

Comment: Short of replacing the bash binary with a wrapper, I don't know think this can be enforced.

Comment: @muru yes, and even if there is a wrapper, `cp /bin/bash.real ./bash` (or even downloading the bash source and compiling it in your home) can easily circumvent it. The problem is --- **why** the OP wants to do that? Probably the problem lies there.

Answer (score 3):

...why? Probably there is a better solution, so if you state *why* probably we can suggests some more sound solutions. Remember that the shell is used not only by users, but also by a lot system processes.

Anyway, `bash` (the default shell) when starts it will (but see later) execute a series of system-wide scripts. The shell can start as interactive or non-interactive, and as login or non-login shell (see `man bash` and search for "INVOCATION" for details).

Basically, when a user starts a shell in a terminal in a graphic session, bash is invoked as interactive, non-login shell and will execute `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started,
>   bash
>          reads and executes commands from  /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if
>          these  files  exist.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.
>          The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and  execute  commands
>          from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

So you can add commands there. Be careful though, errors here can make your system very hard to recover.

#### executive summary (tested)

Edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` and, AFTER the line that says

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

add for example:

```
echo "Hello $USER, you started a new shell"
```

and from a terminal:

```
[romano:~] % bash
Hello romano, you started a new shell
romano@RRyS:~$
```

If you want to run a script here, be careful and double check, like

```
if [ -x /full/path/to/script ]; then 
     /full/path/to/script  # double check here 
fi
```

double check that `/full/path/to/script` does not call `bash` in interactive mode, or you'll have a nice endless loop here.

#### caveat:

This is not at all **enforced**: 
other shells (`zsh`, `tcsh`, `dash`) will behave differently and will use different files. And obviously any user can call the shell with

```
bash --norc --noprofile
```

and have the script files skipped.

---

There is even an example in the 14.04 `/etc/bash.bashrc` (probably a remnant from when Ubuntu switched to `sudo...`) to hint the user to use `sudo` instead of logging in as root:

```
# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
        cat <<-EOF
        To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
        See "man sudo_root" for details.

        EOF
    fi
    esac
fi
```

...but this is code archeology ;-).

Comment: Why so much headache when there is [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)?

Comment: @cremefraiche, because the shell executable is opened thousands of times by all the system scripts of the system. So the script you write should be efficient, ready to run heavily in parallel, identify the user shell case among the other, and then find which user called it on which tty. Mind to provide an example?

Comment: Do you understand how inotify/incron works? Your comments suggest otherwise.

Comment: Maybe no. I am waiting for the example, I am every time ready to learn something new.

Comment: I checked with `inotifywatch -e open /bin/bash`. Without spawning ANY shell (I use `zsh`), just using the system normally, in 30 seconds I have:   `inotifywatch -v -e open /bin/bash` --- waited 30 seconds ... `    `total  open  filename
7      7     /bin/bash`. My point proven; waiting.

Comment: I am writing my response now.

Comment: It seems my use of IN_ALL_ACCESS rule with incron is not appropriate, although there are more things I would like to fiddle with. I will save and delete my answer, then come back to it later tonight or tomorrow and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to make this enforced?

Comment: You can use PAM to enforce things on [login](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) but short of changing the `bash` executable (possible but delicate) I do not see how. And again, if you could explain **why** you ever want to do something like that, maybe we can find a more logical solution. The shell is a basic tool in Unix; limiting it's access is normally a no-no.

Comment: @nyesss please read the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: For every shell that is running or will be run in future I want to run a script within them that will check the existence of certain variable in env and do certain things depending on that.

Comment: @nyesss, the shell is run for a lot of things; do you want your script be run when network manager do a new connection? Or when the system starts up or suspend? It's still not clear at all. And any user can add, remove or change an environment variable.

Comment: I want the script ran for every scenario in which the shell is ran.

Comment: Either `/etc/profile` or `/etc-bash.bashrc` is run for any shell, except when it's explicitly asked for not to. To enforce things is more complex and you should look at [AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) for example. Unfortunately you're still too vague --- I can't help any more than this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'run at all times', so I can't answer that part, but for the rest.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables has a great explanation under the 'System-wide environment variables' section.

But here's what you need to know. Login shells and interactive non-login shells are controlled by different files. So if you want your script to run when ALL shells are started, you will need to source your script in both places, or place it in both places.

**Make a script run when any login shell is executed:**

> Quote from the above source: Files with the .sh extension in the /etc/profile.d directory get executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh), as well as by the DisplayManager when the desktop session loads.

So simply place your script in the /etc/profile.d directory, and give it a .sh extension.

**Make a script run when any interactive non-login shell is executed:**

Pretty much the same as before, except this time it's not a directory, but a file.

/etc/bash.bashrc will be sourced when any interactive non-login shell is executed. This means you can either place the contents of your script directly in /etc/bash.bashrc, or you can source your script from there. If your script is located in /etc/myscript.sh you can source it by adding the `source /etc/myscript.sh` to the /etc/bash.bashrc file.